# React - map is not a function when I use with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to display the list of authors from my API, I've created simple component, and am using `axios`.  My API looks like this:

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/booker/api/authors"
        }
    ],
    "content": [
        {
            "authorId": 4,
            "firstName": "Tonyslav",
            "lastName": "Shamal",
            "webPage": "www.tonisha.gov",
            "dateCreated": "2021-12-15T11:58:28.829+00:00",
            "numberOfBooks": 13,
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "books",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/booker/api/books/author/4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "authorId": 6,
            "firstName": "Georgio",
            "lastName": "Martinez",
            "webPage": "www.got.gov",
            "dateCreated": "2021-12-15T11:58:28.829+00:00",
            "numberOfBooks": 16,
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "books",
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/booker/api/books/author/6"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

And my React components looks like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Authors = () => {
    const [authors, setAuthors] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/booker/api/authors')
            .then(res => {
                setAuthors(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {authors.map(author => (
                <div className="card" key={author.content.authorId}>
                    {author.content.firstName}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Authors;
```

This is my error from the console

```
TypeError: authors.map is not a function
```

Can anybody try to help me with this, i can not solve this error.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting an array from the API. Can you console.log res.data and show us the result

Comment: The first character in your data is `{`. That doesn't start an array. Why should it have a `map` method? You can't just ignore entire levels of your data structure.

Comment: Your response is not an array, it's an object

Comment: `map` is a method of the built-in object `Array` MDN Link : [#](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The response is an object, not an array, so you can't map over it.
You probably want something closer to this:

```js
.then(res => {
    setAuthors(res.data.content);
})
```

Assuming you want to loop over that array.
Then the rendering would look something like this:

```js
<div>
    {authors.map(author => (
        <div className="card" key={author.authorId}>
            {author.firstName}
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the help.  I have just a quick question,  can I fetch links like this, {author.links.href} ?